# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2

Tags: java, maven

I know this is due to the fact that one or more jar files are corrupted in my ~/.m2/ repository but i cant actually figure out which jar file(s) has been corrupted or which jars, I am required to delete and re-download.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-                 plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project CRUDWebAppMavenized: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main :     Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/hp/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-   compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/hp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/hp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-api-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/hp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-   manager/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/hp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Which Java version? ('Unsupported major.minor version 52.0')?

Comment: @khmarbaise Well, I got my problem resolved when I updated maven dependency of maven-compiler-plugin to its latest release i.e., changed version from 2.3.2 to 3.1 in pom.xml. It now builds successfully both on java 7 as well as java 8. For maven, I am using latest m2e eclipse plugin.

Comment: You updated a dependency of the maven-compiler plugin ? Why not updating the maven-compiler-plugin itself? And which dependency did you update?

Comment: @khmarbaise I mean, i updated the maven-compiler-plugin itself to its latest release. All other maven-compiler-plugin dependencies were obviously automatically updated.

Comment: @GirirajSharma **what steps** did you update the maven-compiler-plugin?